# Conditionally registered variables are considered defined, even when the condition is false

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements

Apologies for lack of clarify, rewriting my ask:

I am struggling to get the appropriate *start_index* value passed on to the third task below "**Echo parameters**". If *user_defined_index is ""* I want the **echo unique UIDs** task to execute and output passed in the start_index variable. Likewise if *user_define_index is not ""* I want the second task below to execute and populate the start_index variable. I essentially need to pass either *A* or *B* to the **echo parameters** task.

The **Echo parameters** task expects to get some UIDs. The first task *autogenerates UIDs* based on what you see in the shell command. the second task allows for user to specify UIDs. So whichever ***WHEN*** command is valid that set of UIDs need to get used by the third task. Using debug statements I have confirmed that both *ECHO UNIQUE UIDS* and *CAPTURE USER DEFINED UIDs* tasks work fine and the corresponding register variables have the right data.

My issue is 3rd task only picks up values from the 1st task regardless, whether it be auto generated values or blank with skipped equals true.

I need the correct corresponding value in the start_index to be fed into the 3rd task.

```
  - name: echo unique UIDs
    shell:  echo $(((0x$(hostid) + $(date '+%s'))*100000 + {{ item[0] }}*100000 + {{ start_stress_index }}))
    with_indexed_items:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
    register: start_index
    when: user_defined_index == ""
    changed_when: False

  - name: Capture user defined UIDs
    shell: echo '{{ user_defined_index }}' | tr , '\n'
    with_indexed_items:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
    register: start_index
    when: user_defined_index != ""
    changed_when: False

  - name: Echo parameters
    command: echo --cfg='{{ start_index }}' --si={{ item[1].stdout }}
    with_together:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
      - "{{ start_index.results }}"
```

For the above regardless of user_define_index output from the echo unique UIDs always gets passed through to the 3rd task. After googling I finally found a potential solution to use the **ternary** filter:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33827

I have modified my code to be:

```
  - name: echo unique UIDs
    shell:  echo $(((0x$(hostid) + $(date '+%s'))*100000 + {{ item[0] }}*100000 + {{ start_stress_index }}))
    with_indexed_items:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
    register: start_auto_index
    when: user_defined_index == ""
    changed_when: False

  - name: Capture user defined UIDs
    shell: echo '{{ user_defined_index }}' | tr , '\n'
    with_indexed_items:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
    register: start_user_index
    when: user_defined_index != ""
    changed_when: False

  - name: Echo parameters
    command: echo --cfg='{{ start_index }}' --si={{ item[1].stdout }}
    with_together:
      - "{{ load_cfg }}"
      - "{{ ((start_auto_index is not skipped)|ternary(start_auto_index,start_user_index))['results'] }}"
```

However, I still have same issue as with my first example when i run the above I again only get output from *start_auto_index* sent to 3rd task **echo parameters** no matter what i do with user_defined_index.

I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: i have rewritten my question, hopefully make a lot more sense. also @techraf the link does appear to have a working example, but i could not get it to work. i still get the same result, see my new comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation**

The problem is that your tasks contain a loop and in such case Ansible returns separate statuses for the task and each loop iteration.

With `start_auto_index is not skipped` you check the status of the whole task, but it is iterations that get status "skipped".

**Solution**

Since your conditional `user_defined_index` for the tasks containing the loop is constant for each loop iteration, all iterations will have the same skipped-status, you can modify the condition in the `Echo parameters` task to checking just one of them:

```
"{{ ((start_auto_index[0] is not skipped)|ternary(start_auto_index,start_user_index))['results'] }}"
```

---

<sup>Besides, in the `Echo parameters` task `with_together` does not seem to serve any function, as you don't refer to the `item[0]`.</sup>

Comment: omgosh thanks so much. Your solution worked with slapping **results** in but yours did the trick...thanks!!

`"{{ ((start_auto_index.results[0] is not skipped)|ternary(start_auto_index,start_user_index))['results'] }}"`